# How to tell if recaptcha is solved?

Tags: selenium, recaptcha

I am using python selenium to do some automation work.Yet it's hard to bypass recaptcha.So I decided to solve recaptcha manually.Here is the outline:

```
#run script
#pause
#solve recaptcha myself
#continue script
```

I want my script continue running the moment after I solved recaptcha manually. So,the tricky point is how to tell  if recaptcha is solved.
Any idea will be appreciated!!!

Comment: A lot will depend on How you `#solve recaptcha myself`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have given us a list and expect us to build it for you?

That's not how it works.  That being said... I am interested in Captcha.  In terms of solving captcha, I recommend 2captcha:

```
import requests
from time import sleep

# Add these values
API_KEY = ''  # Your 2captcha API KEY
site_key = ''  # site-key, read the 2captcha docs on how to get this
url = 'http://somewebsite.com'  # example url
proxy = '127.0.0.1:6969'  # example proxy

proxy = {'http': 'http://' + proxy, 'https': 'https://' + proxy}

s = requests.Session()

# here we post site key to 2captcha to get captcha ID (and we parse it here too)
captcha_id = s.post("http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={}&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey={}&pageurl={}".format(API_KEY, site_key, url), proxies=proxy).text.split('|')[1]
# then we parse gresponse from 2captcha response
recaptcha_answer = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id), proxies=proxy).text
print("solving ref captcha...")
while 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY' in recaptcha_answer:
    sleep(5)
    recaptcha_answer = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(API_KEY, captcha_id), proxies=proxy).text
recaptcha_answer = recaptcha_answer.split('|')[1]

# we make the payload for the post data here, use something like mitmproxy or fiddler to see what is needed
payload = {
    'key': 'value',
    'gresponse': recaptcha_answer  # This is the response from 2captcha, which is needed for the post request to go through.
    }


# then send the post request to the url
response = s.post(url, payload, proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: Thanks,man.This might be a good idea to solve captcha automatically.

Comment: @bowen No worries.  I haven't really got into captcha much myself.  Plan to look at it eventually but 2captcha is the best you can get.  The documentation is great.  Deathbycaptcha is another but its severely lacking documentation :)

Comment: Hi,man,sorry to bother you,but I met a strange problem.I tried to register 2captcha,but I failed to pass the "Type the two words" section continuously.I
typed the two words I saw,also I put a space between them.Do you know the right way to solve this?Thanks.
[Link](https://2captcha.com/auth/register)

Comment: @bowen That's a question for their support not me.  I have no idea what that's about.  Try and google it or ask them if you're stuck.  I haven't looked into captcha in months

Comment: Ok.Thanks anyway,have a nice day!

Comment: @bowen No worries, contact support if you are stuck.  They want to make money so they will be nice haha